# SBS2011, Hyper-V expand VHD size

Tags: hyper-v

As disk space is getting very low on our virtual server I wanted to expand the the VHD with the appropriate Microsoft wizard.
I changed the size from 160 to 200GB, started the server again but still the drive is only 160 in size.

Though checking the size with the Hyper-V when the server is offline states that the disk size is 200GB as configured.

Any idea what could causes this?

**Hyper-V, version: 6.1.7601.17514**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to extend the volume in the guest using disk management.
(Screenshot shows shrink, but you must extend)
[image]